# How to change the return value of operator=?

Tags: c++

So i have been creating this "framework" thing that basically puts together source code (for shaders). I thought i was pretty clever when i came up with the idea of making a statement class and overloading all of its operators (changing their meaning completely) to form other statements in a natural way. It looks like this:

```
class Statement {

public:
    Statement operator=(const Statement &other) const;
    Statement operator+(const Statement &other) const;
    ...

}
```

However, when i thought i was done, it turned out that the operator= completely disregarded the return value and instead just always returned the object before the '='. Do i understand it correctly that there is no way to accomplish this?

EDIT: Ok, sorry, the example i provided compiles (i had the operator overloaded in A too which didn't work).

**EDIT 2: The operator= is actually const on purpose:** Its intended meaning is to create a new assignment statement object.

**Example:**

```
Block b; // Represents a sequence of commands.
Statement var1, var2; // Represent some variables.
...
b.append(var1 = var2);
```

Expected: b includes the command var1 = var2;

Observed: b includes var1;

**Resolved:** The problem was because i was using a derived class instead of Statement which used its default operator=. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Your code compiles fine with VS2010.

Comment: What do you mean by "disregarded the return value and instead just always returned the object before the '='"? Could you add a complete example along with expected and observed output?

Comment: @Dethroc: Your example is still missing a lot of code (How is `Statement::operator=` implemented? How is `Block` implemented?). [I've tried filling in the blanks, and it works for me](http://ideone.com/5eSls).

Comment: @Mankarse I'm sorry about that. I couldn't really copy the actual code because there is a ton of other things but your implementation is what i meant. I have now found the problem though, it was due to the fact i was using a derived class instead of Statement and now it works. Thanks for the effort and i'm sorry you wasted time on this, now i realize i was being pretty unclear. At least i upvoted all your comments. :)

Comment: You should read about [expression templates](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Expression-template). What you do has some runtime cost, expression templates can make it all a compile-time cost. They require a good grounding in C++, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you declare one, a class always has an implicitly-declared copy-assignment operator with the signature:

```
Statement& operator=(const Statement&)
```

Note it is *not* const, so is preferred when assigning to a non-const object, because your assignment operator is const. [**Edit**: my mistake, the `const` assignment operator suppresses the implicit one, so the unconventional `const`-qualified assignment operator should be used.]

(how do you expect to assign to I.e. modify, a const object?)

(N.B. to be more accurate, the implicitly-declared assignment operator could have the signature `Statement& operator=(Signature&)` if a sub-object declares an assignment operator with that signature, but that's not the case in your example.)

Comment: To be pedantic, a class doesn't _always_ have an implicitly declared copy assignment operator even if you don't declare one. Try containing a const or reference member

Comment: @Dave : It will still be implicitly declared, just not implicitly defined (or to be pedantic, it will be implicitly defined as deleted).

Comment: [class.copy]/18 "If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared _implicitly_."

Comment: Well the point was that the assignment operator wasn't actually going to change the value of the object but rather create a new statement with the meaning of "original = value". Removing const didn't help.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `Statement operator=(const Statement &other) const;` _is_ a copy assignment operator (see `[class.copy]/17`) and so `Statement& operator=(const Statement&)` is not implicitly created in this case.

Comment: @Mankarse, wow ... I thought it said non-const, but you're right, it doesn't. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Detheroc, a good rule of thumb is don't try to be clever and overload operators with an unconventional meaning. If the assignment operator usually modifies the object and returns the object itself, you will almost always make life difficult if you use different semantics.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: As far as I can tell, Detheroc is trying to use [expression templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates), which commonly call for unusual operator overload signatures and semantics.

Comment: Alright, it turns out, the problem was caused by the fact that i was using a derived class, which apparently prioritized its own implicit operator, but i wouldn't have thought of that without your answer, so thanks and sorry i kind of messed it up.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine (and it works with [g++-4.5.1](http://ideone.com/HS0ZE), [g++-4.3.4](http://ideone.com/6TNbV), Clang and VS2010). If it does not work then there must either be something wrong with your compiler, or there must be something that you are not telling us.

Comment: I don't see how this warrants a downvote (unless it was flagged as 'not an answer')...

Comment: Code containing a `const` copy-assignment operator is not "fine" especially when the question asks why the return value of the assignment operator doesn't match what is expected. The reason it doesn't match expectations is because the copy-assignment operator is `const` which is abnormal and confusing.

Comment: @Jonathan : You're remarking about `Statement`, but the actual compilable code (involving `A` and `B`) doesn't have that problem -- presumably this answer is only referring to the latter. EDIT: Aaaand now that code's gone. :-/